# MySQL Query to Find People that have three or more Hobbies in common

Tags: mysql

So, this is an example from a resource I am using to learn the basics of MySQL. This example in particular has me quite stumped at the moment. The example states: Find all persons that have three or more hobbies in common.

In this database, there is a Person table which only has the name as an atttribute and a Hobbies table which only has the names of various hobbies. Each Person has at least one hobby, but they can have several of course.

For my attempt at this, I have only gotten so far as getting the people that have three or more hobbies like this

```
SELECT person_name, COUNT(*) AS num_hobbies FROM Person
INNER JOIN Hobbies ON Person.id = Hobbies.id
GROUP BY person_name HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

So, to be clear as to what I am looking for, say a Person "John" has hobbies {A, B, C, D} and another Person "Dave" has hobbies {A, C, D, E, F} then these two would be outputted since they share the hobbies {A, C, D}.
Looking for some assistance on how I can get the hobbies that are in common. Only thing that comes to mind is possibly a subquery, but not sure how exactly to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy. You want to find person pairs sharing at least three hobbies. In order to find these, you must query the hobbies table twice. You combine every person's hobby with every other person's same hobby. Then you aggregate by person pairs to see how many joined rows (i.e. same hobbies) they have.

```
select h1.person_id, h2.person_id
from hobbies h1
join hobbies h2 on  h2.person_id > h1.person_id
                and h2.hobby_id  = h1.hobby_id
group by h1.person_id, h2.person_id
having count(*) > 3;
```

You can use this result to access the persons table in order to get additional data. E.g.:

```
select 
  p1.person_id, p1.first_name, p1.last_name,
  p2.person_id, p2.first_name, p2.last_name
from
(
  select h1.person_id as p1_id, h2.person_id as p2_id
  from hobbies h1
  join hobbies h2 on  h2.person_id > h1.person_id
                  and h2.hobby_id  = h1.hobby_id
  group by h1.person_id, h2.person_id
  having count(*) > 3
) matches
join persons p1 on p1.person_id = matches.p1_id
join persons p2 on p2.person_id = matches.p2_id;
```